# will_paginate Api to send number of items per_page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm implementing e-commerce app which has Product model it contains many products, I want to display the limited number of product per page In the app if we scroll the page it should load the remaining product, Like amazon or flipkart app. How to achieve this in rails?

I have added the will_paginate, It will display the first n number items which is specified in will_paginate per_page. How to display the remaining items? How can I handle that in api's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) gem or [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem. I think active_admin uses kaminari inside it.

if you follow there docs (behaviour of both gems is same)
it adds page numbers on view. If you want to automatically load next content here is a idea, you have to google out how you will achive that.

show first x element on screen followed by div with loading icon. add js  pagescroll event and check whether this div is visible in screen or not. if yes send ajax request for next elements. after success-full ajax request remove this loading icon div and append results and at end again add loading div so that on page scroll it again send ajax request.

here is jquery sudo code (note you need to check and edit code this is just sudo code)

```
page = 0

$(window).unbind("scroll")
handel_scrolling = function(){

if($(".loading").offset()){
    //this if checks whether loading div appears in screen or not
    if($(".loading").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()) {
        page++
        url = "myurl?page=" + page

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
        ele = $(".loading")
                $(".loading").remove()
                $(".list").append(data)
        $(".dashboard-list").append(ele)
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("something went wrong")
            }
        })
    }}
}
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
handel_scrolling()
});
```

Comment: will_paginate is send the number(ex: 10) of items but In android app it will display the first 10 then how it will call for remaining items?

Comment: if there is no parameter called page in URL it consider page = 0 (or 1 I am not sure) and return first n elements. if you want to get next n elements you can call same url with page = 1 (or 2 if initial page = 1) like myurl?page=1

Comment: will_paginate will display the first 10 items, how to display the next items? How I can handle the api for that?

Comment: show me your controller and view part  not understand - How I can handle the api for that?

Comment: each time api will be called from android app to load more items, How api will provide the more items for each call?

Comment: how you are loading first time? there should be some get action right? if this get url is like localhost:3000/products next set of products will be localhost:3000/products?page=2